# Passing template class instance to a constructor of another class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

My code:

BlockyWorld.hpp

```
#ifndef BLOCKYWORLD_H
#define BLOCKYWORLD_H

#include <CImg.h>

namespace logic {
  class BlockyWorld {
  public:
    BlockyWorld( const CImg<float>* heightmap );
  };
}

#endif // BLOCKYWORLD_H
```

BlockyWorld.cpp

```
#include "BlockyWorld.hpp"

namespace logic {
  BlockyWorld::BlockyWorld( const CImg<float>* heightmap ) {}
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <CImg.h>
#include "logic/BlockyWorld.hpp"
//...
CImg<float> heigthMap;
logic::BlockyWorld world( &heigthMap );
//...
```

I get alot of errors while compiling:

main.cpp:

```
include\logic\blockyworld.hpp(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
include\logic\blockyworld.hpp(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
main.cpp(85): error C2664: 'logic::BlockyWorld::BlockyWorld(const logic::BlockyWorld &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'cimg_library::CImg<float>' to 'const int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

BlockyWorld.hpp & cpp

```
include\logic\blockyworld.hpp(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
include\logic\blockyworld.hpp(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
include\logic\blockyworld.cpp(4): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
include\logic\blockyworld.cpp(4): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
```

I don't think it's a circular inclusion error which sometimes causes these kinds of errors for me=).
I must be defining constructor wrong or maybe I'm defining implementation wrong? Was searching for an answer for abount an hour now so I would really use an explanation now.

And just to clarify - I'm not a beginner c/c++ programmer but these templates are confusing :(

Have a nice day and thank your for your answers.

Comment: `BlockyWorld::BlockyWorld( const CImg<float>& heightmap )` isn't matching the declared signature: `BlockyWorld( const CImg<float>* heightmap )`!

Comment: sry error while typing question=)

Comment: Where is the definition of CImg?

Comment: CImg is a from a CImg library:
http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html

Comment: Are you sure the `CImg` class is not in `cimg` or `cimg_library` namespace? The examples from [here](http://kiharalab.org/genPortrait/src/CImg-1.2.5/documentation/CImg_reference.pdf) seem to be using `using namespace cimg_library;`

Comment: It looks like the compiler doesn't recognize the Constructor as such, and complains that your function doesn't have a return type specified. Are you sure you didn't mistype the constructor name in the real-life file?

Comment: No I was missing namespace declaration for CImg class which was in cimg_library=) These compiler errors are so not helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CImg` appears to be part of the `cimg_library` namespace.

Either add `using namespace cimg_library` to the top of your BlockyWorld.hpp file, or change the function signature to use the namespace like so:

```
BlockyWorld( const cimg_library::CImg<float>* heightmap );
```

Along with πάντα ῥεῖ's suggestion of matching up your pointer and reference types.